# Swift function execute lazy like Haskell

Tags: swift, haskell, lazy-evaluation

Hope to understand if Swift compile chain calling a function like Haskell,

```
let x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    func doubleMe(x: Int) -> Int {
        return x * 2
    }

    x.map(doubleMe)
    .map(doubleMe)
    .map(doubleMe)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have a lazy version if you use the `lazy` property:

```
let double : (Int) -> Int = { $0 * 2 }


let result = [1, 2, 3].lazy.map(double).map(double).map(double)

for elem in result {
    print(elem)
}

print(Array(result))
```